# Radical IQ challenge

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence, sequence

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #2: IQ Puzzle Parody](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7376/)</sub>

---

Can you find out the next one in the sequence, how it's different to the ones before it, and explain the pattern?

1
10
11
20
31
52
121
200
314
512
851
1228

Comment: This sequence also exists on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A102626)

Comment: @JLee yeah, I wasn't sure how best to make that work. I can remove that header if it helps?

Comment: @JLee my thought at the time is that normally an IQ test might simply have a similar sequence without the 'twist'.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

First, take

> The powers of 2, from 2<sup>0</sup> to 2<sup>10</sup>:
>
> 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ..., 2048

And now

> Based on its position, convert it into that number base. So for instance the second position is now in binary, the third in ternary, etc.

This gives:

> 1 Base 1 = 1
> 2 Base 2 = 10
> 4 Base 3 = 11
> 8 Base 4 = 20
> 16 Base 5 = 31
> .
> .
> .
> 2048 Base 12 = 1228

So the next number is:

> 4096 Base 13 = **1B31**
>
> This differs to the rest as it is the first in the sequence containing a letter!